# Truncate Table With Partitions - aligned/ non-aligned indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, partitioning, truncate

SQL Server 2016 introduced a modification to the TRUNCATE TABLE statement which allows you to truncate a specific partition or set of partitions from a table:

> TRUNCATE TABLE < tablename > WITH (PARTITIONS (< partition_id >));

An [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4436/sql-server-2016-truncate-table-with-partitions/) about the TRUNCATE TABLE WITH PARTITIONS contains the next note:

> To start using the new TRUNCATE TABLE statement option, make sure that
>   all your table indexes are aligned with the source table. If there are
>   non-aligned indexes in your table, drop or disable these indexes,
>   truncate the partition(s) you want then rebuild the indexes again.

Does SQL Server 2016 provide an easy way (e.g. a query) to determine if the indexes of the partitioned tables are all aligned? (I want to avoid having to drop or disable indexes.)

---

**Update 1**

Example output of [link](https://littlekendra.com/2016/03/15/find-the-partitioning-key-on-an-existing-table-with-partition_ordinal/):

*One index consists of 2 columns, but only one column is used in the partition function.

Is the index PK_TEST1 aligned or non-aligned?*

- index_name: **PK_TEST1**
- partition_function: psTEST1
- partition_ordinal: 1
- key_ordinal: 1
- is_included_column: 0
- columnName: **COLUMN1**

#

- index_name: **PK_TEST1**
- partition_function: psTEST1
- partition_ordinal: 0
- key_ordinal: 2
- is_included_column: 0
- columnName: **COLUMN2**

Comment: The post - [Partitioned Tables with Non-Aligned Indexes](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/partitioned-tables-with-non-aligned-indexes/) - has a query that may provide the information you are looking for.

Comment: @ScottHodgin Thank you for the link, but which column or value can I use to differentiate aligned and non-aligned indxes? I've also checked the [link](https://littlekendra.com/2016/03/15/find-the-partitioning-key-on-an-existing-table-with-partition_ordinal/) as well, but it's still unclear for me.

Comment: @ScottHodgin Please have a look at 'Update 1' in the OP.

Comment: If the index includes the partition column as one of the key columns *and* is defined as using the partition scheme, then it is aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put this query together for you that should show you what you want.  You can add additional where clauses to trim it further if you need to.

```
;WITH CTE_PartCount AS
    (
    SELECT P.object_id
        , P.index_id
        , COUNT(P.partition_number) AS PartitionCount
    FROM sys.partitions AS P
    GROUP BY P.object_id
        , P.index_id
    )
, CTE_Objects AS
    (
    SELECT O.object_id
        , O.name AS ObjectName
        , S.name AS SchemaName
        , I.index_id
        , I.name AS IndexName
        , I.type_desc AS IndexType
    FROM sys.objects AS O
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS S ON S.schema_id = O.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS I ON I.object_id = O.object_id
    WHERE O.is_ms_shipped = 0
        AND O.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
    )
, CTE_Summary AS
    (
    SELECT O.object_id
        , O.ObjectName
        , O.SchemaName
        , O.IndexName
        , O.IndexType
        , PC.PartitionCount
        , TablePartCount = FIRST_VALUE(PC.PartitionCount) OVER (PARTITION BY O.object_id ORDER BY O.object_id, O.index_id)
    FROM CTE_Objects AS O
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_PartCount AS PC ON PC.object_id = O.object_id AND PC.index_id = O.index_id
    )
SELECT S.object_id
    , S.SchemaName
    , S.ObjectName
    , S.IndexName
    , S.IndexType
    , S.PartitionCount
    , IsPartitioned = CASE WHEN S.TablePartCount <> 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
    , IsAligned = CASE WHEN S.TablePartCount = S.PartitionCount THEN 'ALIGNED' ELSE '' END
FROM CTE_Summary AS S
```